# Oxidation of alkenes by selenium dioxide to diketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-oxidation

I know that $\ce{SeO2}$ readily affects the allylic position. The reaction mechanism of this reaction goes like this:

[image: Seleniumdioxide oxidation]
(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_dioxide#/media/File:Seleniumdioxide_oxidation.svg); License: Public Domain)

But, in my book, there's another reaction given as an exception:

[image: formation of alpha-diketone]

Here, an $\alpha$-diketone is formed.

Why and how is this alternative product formed? What is the mechanism for this product?

Comment: $\ce{\alpha}$-diketones are often formed when $\ce{SeO2}$ reacts with **alkynes** that don't have any hydrogens on the carbons adjacent to the acetylenic carbons.  Are you sure your book showed an alkene?

Comment: Yes, for sure, I have checked it again and its an alkene not alkyne. I know that alkyne reaction but this is not that.

Comment: I found formation of an $\alpha$-diketone from a ketone, but not from an alkene.